# Disable geometry option includehead for Titel page

Tags: titles, geometry

I am using the geometry package globally like so: `\usepackage[a4paper, includehead, left=3.5cm, right=1.7cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}`

However, for my titlepage I do not want the header space included, so that my content sits 2.5cm below the top. How can I disable this option only for my title page? I am using a KOMA class and \title for my layout.

Comment: You can use \newgeometry to setup the layout for your titlepage but I would simply use \vspace*{-XX} to move the title up.

Comment: Thanks! How can I find out how much space my header occupies? Is that a standard value for the scrreprt class?

Comment: I wouldn't care about it. Place the text on the titlepage so that it looks good (where depends on the content, the font, the font size etc).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to answer or mark as duplicate?